# How to show loading indicator before request done after page(route) changing?

Tags: reactjs

I have protected route, and it works fine for me, but there is 1 case
that I don't not how handle correctly.

When cookie expire and after this I try to visit another page, I need
user even doesn't see content of this page.

So I decide add second check, and I compare prev location with
current, and in case if it's different I show loading indicator and
after check user request I make logout so user cannot see new route
when cokie expire. But maybe there is a way implement this functional
without comparing location?

Here is my component: 
I have isLoading flag, that setting to false after request has
been successful, but after route changes,= this flag already
false so I need check by location as second check.

```
const ProtectedRoute = (
    {component: Component, patch, location: {pathname}, checkAuth, isLoading, prevLocation, isAuth}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth()
  }, [pathname])

  const isRouterChange = () => prevLocation !== pathname

  if (isLoading || isRouterChange()) {
    return <div className='spinner'><Spin size='large'/></div>
  }

  return (
      <Route exact path={patch}>
        {!isAuth ? <Redirect to='login'/> : <Component/>}
      </Route>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the protected route and public route with auth condition makes sense. maybe you can use [Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) component beside those routes. React 16.6 added a  component that lets you “wait” for some code to load and declaratively specify a loading state (like a spinner) while we’re waiting.